# How to Navigate UIViewController from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Hi I'm New to iOS Development and Please give me a solution to navigate to UIViewController from an UIView: This is the code I have used but it is not working

```
acceptedJobDetailViewController *acceptedJobDetailViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"acceptedJobDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:acceptedJobDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Also i tried this below code to push the viewcontroller but that is also not working, Please help me to sort out this:

```
[appDelegate.navControl pushViewController:acceptedJobDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already added `NavigationController` in your `storyboard` and you are trying to push screen from `UIView` Class than use below code :

```
UIViewController *superViewController =  (UIViewController*)[self nextResponder];
UINavigationController *navigationController = superViewController.navigationController;
[navigationController pushViewController:<YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_OBJECT> animated:YES];
```

if you haven't and any navigation please add it before your ViewController like below

```
Select ViewController -> Go to Editor Menu -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller
```

Now Navigation Controller added into your storyboard now do what you are doing previously.

```
acceptedJobDetailViewController *acceptedJobDetailViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"acceptedJobDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:acceptedJobDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[(UIViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder] navigationController] pushViewController:"your viewcontroller object" animated:NO];
```

Updated to **swift 3**

```
(superview?.next? as? UIViewController)?.navigationController?.pushViewController("your viewcontroller object", animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

please add navigation controller in your storyboard.

```
step -1: select acceptedJobDetailViewController from storyboard.
step -2: now go to Editor>EmbedIn>NavigationController
step -3: now below code and run your project


acceptedJobDetailViewController *acceptedJobDetailViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"acceptedJobDetailViewController"];
```